# Why is a Joptionpane not modal on top of a JDialog

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, joptionpane, jdialog

I have used a JOptionpane as an error message which is invoked by a wrong user input on a JDialog.

Modality Type : APPLICATION MODAL
modalExclusionType : APPLICATION_EXCLUDE

The problem is when the JOptionpane  appears the JDialog is still functional.
Below is the code of invoking the JOptionpane

```
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JDialog's name, "you must fill in all required fields", "Error!", 0);
```

Is there any way to fix this?

here is a minimal example programme

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Modality extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public Modality() {
        initComponents();
    }


    private void initComponents() {

        jDialog1 = new javax.swing.JDialog();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jDialog1.setModalExclusionType(java.awt.Dialog.ModalExclusionType.APPLICATION_EXCLUDE);
        jDialog1.setModalityType(java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);

        jButton2.setText("JOptionpane");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("Type in the textfield while the jdialog is visible");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jDialog1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jDialog1.getContentPane());
        jDialog1.getContentPane().setLayout(jDialog1Layout);
        jDialog1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jDialog1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jDialog1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(109, 109, 109)
                        .addComponent(jButton2))
                    .addGroup(jDialog1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(76, 76, 76)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 154, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jDialog1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(50, 50, 50)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)))
                .addContainerGap(82, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jDialog1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jDialog1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(111, 111, 111)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(96, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText(" View JDialog");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(97, 97, 97)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(122, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(101, 101, 101)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(105, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        jDialog1.pack();
        jDialog1.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jDialog1, "Hello World! What's wrong with focus?");
    }



    public static void main(String args[]) {


        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Modality.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Modality.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Modality.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Modality.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>


        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Modality().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JDialog jDialog1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;

}
```

Comment: yes.Other than the modality problem it works fine

Comment: Are you sure?: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JDialog name,` looks a bit skanky to me. You can't call a method this way. Regardless, you should post a [small compilable example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows us your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry it's my fault. By "JDialog name " I tried to mean the name of the JDialog

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23722858/edit), correct your question's code, and then consider creating and posting your [minimal code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok I posted a working example

Comment: Thanks, that makes all the difference. 1+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

> modalExclusionType : APPLICATION_EXCLUDE

Per the Window API:

> Specifies the modal exclusion type for this window. **If a window is modal excluded, it is not blocked by some modal dialogs**. See Dialog.ModalExclusionType for possible modal exclusion types.

If you don't set this, then the JOptionPane blocks the dialog window just fine.